# how to check if a keybinding is os level keybinding or application keybinding?

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

eg:

In macOS, Command + shift + 5, screenshot utility is system level keybinding so it takes precedence over any application keybinding which conflicts with this

In macOS, Control + Shift + f, toggle full screen seems to be application level keybinding since it doesn't work in emacs as C-S-f is used for forward-sexp, but works in all other apps

Is there any way to know whether keybinding is os level or application level in macOS and also in linux (ubuntu)?

Answer (score 0):

The standard Fullscreen key combo is is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd> ...

...but I think the global determiner is "does the app itself have that menu command?"
If it does, it can be overridden for that app only; if it doesn't & still works, then it is truly global. There are exceptions... some apps just completely ignore the standard Mac toolbox, so are neither one nor the other.